# WLAN driver Xubuntu 18 Lenovo Legion Y540-15IRH Laptop

Tags: drivers, wireless, iwlwifi

How do I install the wireless drivers in my [Lenovo Legion Y540-15IRH laptop](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/legion_y540-15irh_pg0_hmm_201904.pdf) with an [Intel 9th Gen. Core i7 CPU](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/legion-laptops/legion-y-series/Lenovo-Legion-Y540-15/p/88GMY501214)?

- Card-1: Intel Wireless-AC 9560 (Jefferson Peak) driver: iwlwifi
- Card-2: Realtek is fine with driver r8169 though.

Additional drivers did not show up when I searched. Is there any other driver I need to download from [here](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/se/sv/products/laptops-and-netbooks/legion-series/legion-y540-15irh/downloads)?

[This](https://mxlinux.org/wiki/networking/ndiswrapper/#Installation) did not work by the way as mentioned for utils so now I have a search Windows driver that is unnecessary, would that be easy to remove?

Below is the output of commands ran asked for

Output of  `lspci -nnk | grep -e 0200 - e 0280 -A3`:

```
(standard input):07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
(standard input)-   Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:38cd]
(standard input)-   Kernel driver in use: r8169
(standard input)-   Kernel modules: r8169
grep: e: No such file or directory
grep: 0280: No such file or directory
```

Output of `rfkill list all`:

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep -e 0200 -e 0280 -A3` and also: rfkill list all` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `rfkill list`

Comment: There is no reason to look for a driver when your own question shows, Card-1: Intel Wireless-AC 9560 (Jefferson Peak) driver: iwlwifi

Comment: Please note that your wireless is hard blocked. Please see and follow the duplicate.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to ask another question.  **:-(** Just [ask a new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) instead and refer to this question with a link if it helps provide context.  **:-)**

Answer (score 0):

The key document which explains the use of [apt](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/apt.html) may be helpful. First, the *update* line tells Ubuntu to check the list of repositories and refresh its list of what's available to download.

```
 sudo apt update
```

Next, we tell Ubuntu to get any new items you have installed previously from those repositories.

```
 sudo apt upgrade
```

Now that all the current apps and dependencies are up to date, we go get the [ndis](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper) tools.

```
 sudo apt install ndisgtk ndiswrapper-utils
```

Once that's done, then you can proceed with https://mxlinux.org/wiki/networking/ndiswrapper/#Installation

```
Click Start menu > System > Windows Wireless Drivers   
Click on the Install New Driver button and note where you told it to save it to  
Navigate to the folder where you stored the downloaded driver folder   
Highlight the *.inf file, and click OK   
Jump to the Blacklist section below to finish.
```

Comment: I have not seen ndiswrapper work successfully in many years. moreover, it is not needed for any Intel device. Also, ndiswrapper requires Windows XP drivers which we do not have.

Comment: true story for me, it did not work